# Google Places API: The Places API could not find the user's location

Tags: google-places-api, cllocationmanager, cllocation

In AppDelegate, I have the following code to allow location tracking:

```
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
```

In my ViewController, I make a Google Places request:

```
    placesClient = GMSPlacesClient.shared()
    placesClient.currentPlace(callback: { (placeLikelihoodList, error) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            print("Pick Place error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        if let placeLikelihoodList = placeLikelihoodList {
            let place = placeLikelihoodList.likelihoods.first?.place
            if let place = place {
                print("Place:\(place.name)")
            }
        }
    })
```

The error message is:

[0] (null)  "NSLocalizedFailureReason" : "The Places API could not find the user\'s location. This may be because the user has not allowed the application to access location information."

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to add the NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key to your Info.plist file.

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Show your location on the map</string>
```

In addition, choose a location for your simulator. Go to your simulator, Debug -> Location -> Custom Location